# Azure ImageSearch API filter transparent images

Tags: bing-search

I've migrating **Bing ImageSearch** to **Azure ImageSearch** through. It works perfectly through GET request sent to `https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image`

As I see `Bing Search` web UI let you filter images with **transparent background**:

`https://www.bing.com/images/search?scope=images&pq=boy&sc=8-3&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=36DB1C9A081B4DAEB71B8161E26E8E6C&q=boy&qft=+filterui:photo-transparent&FORM=R5IR25`

However, Azure ImageSearch documentation does not show any option to filter images with transparent background: `https://www.bing.com/images/search?scope=images&pq=boy&sc=8-3&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=36DB1C9A081B4DAEB71B8161E26E8E6C&q=boy&qft=+filterui:photo-transparent&FORM=R5IR25`

Is that possible to do that? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. But for some reason it doesn't seem to be documented. 
Try adding this (as you have written above):

```
&qft=+filterui:photo-transparent
```

right after your query string.